# AJAX Returns error when set Content-Type to json

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing simple ajax library for myself, and for some reason I have encountered with error. Here's the sample of code which returns `{}`

```js
var Ajax = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Ajax() {
    }
    Ajax.send = function (params) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        params.error = params.error || function () { };
        params.callback = params.callback || function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                params.success(this);
            }
            else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                params.error(this);
            }
        };
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = params.callback;
        xhttp.open(params.method, params.url, params.async || true);
        for (var header in params.headers) {
            xhttp.setRequestHeader(header, params.headers[header]);
        }
        //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        xhttp.send();
    };
    return Ajax;
}());
Ajax.send({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://rectangular-nephew.glitch.me/",
    success: function (e) {
        document.write(e.responseText);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        document.write("Error: " + e.status);
    }
});
```

Everything works fine until I set content type to `application/json`:

```js
var Ajax = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Ajax() {
    }
    Ajax.send = function (params) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        params.error = params.error || function () { };
        params.callback = params.callback || function () {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                params.success(this);
            }
            else if (this.readyState == 4) {
                params.error(this);
            }
        };
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = params.callback;
        xhttp.open(params.method, params.url, params.async || true);
        for (var header in params.headers) {
            xhttp.setRequestHeader(header, params.headers[header]);
        }
        
        ///Here it is
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        xhttp.send();
    };
    return Ajax;
}());
Ajax.send({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://rectangular-nephew.glitch.me/",
    success: function (e) {
        document.write(e.responseText);
    },
    error: function (e) {
        document.write("Error: " + e.status);
    }
});
```

And I have no idea why is that happening. I already set headers on my server:

```
response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
response.set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
```

But it doesn't work either.
So what could be the problem?

Error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rectangular-nephew.glitch.me/'
>   from origin 'https://www.typescriptlang.org' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
>   check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

Comment: But you're not outputting a `content-type` header on the server (or at lesat you don't show that you are). My guess is that's why it's getting blocked since you've expressly said the server must respond with `content-type: application/json`

Comment: I haven't said it, `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` sets header to xhttp response

Comment: No, that simply tells the request what content type you *expect* the server to output. It is still incumbent on the server to actually output a content type header.

Comment: Then how do I tell that my parameters are encoded in JSON

Comment: I mean, I saw a lot of answers with `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` and `xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({a: "b"}))`

Comment: Yeah... actually I'm not sure. Sorry, I'll duck out at this point.

Comment: Lol, I'm stumped too.

Comment: Look in the network log in dev tools; even though the browser blocks you from accessing the response you can still inspect it. Does it arrive with the access control header, and is the output what you expect?

Comment: @Utkanos `Content-type` in the request header refers to the format of the data being sent in the request. `Accept:` states the type that you expect the server to output.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar, you're quite right. My mistake.

Comment: `Content-type` has no meaning in a `GET` request, since you don't send any content.

Comment: If you want to specify that you're expecting a JSON response, it should be `Accept: application/json`

Comment: @Barmar I changed it to POST and error is still there

Comment: I don't think the problem has anything to do with GET vs POST.

Comment: But why are you sending a `Content-type` header if you're not sending any parameters? `xhttp.send()` has no content in it -- there's no JSON there.

Comment: Does your server correctly handle the OPTION verb? The error message states, that the "preflight request's response did not contain the Access-control-allow-origin header". This is an extra request that browsers send via the OPTION verb, before sending cross origin requests. If the response does not contain valid CORS headers, the actual GET/POST/whatever request will not even be sent.